# Express JS node framework did not respond to post() request

Tags: node.js, express, post

I'm following a blog to build my first node API with express framework. But the POST request did not return a response.

```
const app = express();

require('./app/routes')(app, {});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});

module.exports = function(app, db) {
  console.log('reached2');
  app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
    // You'll create your note here.
    console.log('reached3');
    res.send('Hello');
    //res.end();;
  });
};
```

Here are my console logs,

```
reached1
reached2
We are live on 8000
```

Here are my dependencies,

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.28"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  }
```

Im using the [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) client to POST.

[image]

I tried replacing the fat arrow operator with an anonymous function but still doesnt work.

Please point the problem in this code.

Comment: You are exporting a function that calls app.post, but are you actually calling that function anywhere?

Comment: yes, `require('./app/routes')(app, {});` i do see the function is called since the  console logs from that function.

Comment: Voting to close the question since the problem is with the port number. Works on port 3000. Express/Node/Nodemon does say it is listening on port 8000 eventhough it isnt.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your routes in a separate file (which is fairly standard practice), then you need to return a router and tell the express app to use it.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./routes')({});

const app = express();

app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Listening on 8080');
})
```

**routes.js**

```
const express = require('express');

module.exports = (db) => {

    const router = express.Router();

    router.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Hello!');
    })

    // all your other routes here!

    return router;

}
```

Or, alternatively if you want to do it without using using `express.Router()`, you could pass the `app`.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

require('./routes')(app, {});

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Listening on 8080');
})
```

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = (app, db) => {

    app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Hello!');
    })

}
```

Comment: is it possible to do without router? since the blog i follow doesn't i use it.

Comment: @ProgramCpp yep, I've updated my answer with a second example. That way feels less nice though! Have you got a link to the blog?

Comment: Thanks Dan, will try the other option. this is the blog, https://medium.freecodecamp.com/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2

Comment: @ProgramCpp apologies, you don't need to return the app. I've updated the second example again. However, now our apps are the same from what I can see. Are you still having issues with my second example?

Comment: yes, both our code look same but doesn't work. However i have not shared all my code. I have updated my question with screenshot of my client request and response. Hope there is nothing wrong there!

Comment: @ProgramCpp That all looks fine to me. The two above examples should work for you. I've tested them locally and they seem to be fine. Have you tried something other that Postman, like curl (or a Windows equivalent) to make the request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146191/discussion-between-programcpp-and-dan).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing route in a function you can use it directly. Below is the code snippet for the same:

```
const app = express();
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});

app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
    // You'll create your note here.
    res.send('Hello');
});
```